# Extra argument 'delay' in call

Tags: xcode, swift

XCode shows me "Extra argument 'delay' in call" after putting variables in CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation.
Any idea why? Think its a bug.

```
        var direction = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {
            self.NameInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5*direction, 0);
            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This inside a animateTransition function?  If so, can you post the entire function?  Also a description of the animation.

Comment: Bug disappears if you remove the var direction ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the Swift compiler has bad error messages.  Really, really bad error messages.

Here's the fix:

```
var direction = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {
    self.NameInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5*CGFloat(direction), 0)
    //                                                            ^^^^^^^^         ^
    }, completion: nil)
```

The compiler couldn't compile the `animations` block because of the incorrect type.  So it didn't know the type of the block.  It substituted an error type for the block.  Then it tried to find an `animateWithDuration` overload that takes that error type as an argument.  There isn't one, so it chose an overload arbitrarily.  Specifically, it chose the `animateWithDuration(_,animations:)` overload, which doesn't take a `delay` argument.  Hence the error message you received.

Comment: +1 for great explanation, although stylistically I think insane-36's solution (`var direction: CGFloat = 0`) is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with Int and CGFloat types. You are multiplying integer value with some CGFloat value which is undefined. So, if you make sure that the duration is CGFloat type, your problem will be gone.

```
var direction: CGFloat = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
  self.NameInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(5 * direction, 0);

}, completion: nil)
```